# JavaScript validation form

Tags: javascript, html, validation

Could this code be improved? Would you suggest more sophisticated way of doing client-side signup validation?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function validateForm() {
            var name = document.forms["registrationForm"]["username"].value;
            if (name == null || name == "") {
                alert("Name must be filled out");
                return false;
            }
            var password = document.forms["registrationForm"]["password"].value;
            var repeatPassword = document.forms["registrationForm"]["passwordAgain"].value;
            if (password.length < 8) {
                alert("Password should contain 8 symbols or more");
                return false;
            }
            if (password != repeatPassword) {
                alert("Filled out passwords should match");
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<h3>SignUp Form</h3>
<form name="registrationForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" action="registration" method="post">
    Email:<input type="text" name="username"/><br/><br/>
    Password:<input type="password" name="password"/><br/><br/>
    Repeat Password:<input type="password" name="passwordAgain"/><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="signup"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could use the `required` and `minlength` attributes on `<input>`.

Comment: @gcampbell sounds like an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a more sophisticated way of doing client-side validation. This all depends on what your design is (if the customer wants it this way, then that's it), but personally, I'd prefer it if you check the field after I've edited it, and if it is not correct, that you change the styling on the field, maybe set an error label.

Right now you're throwing alert dialogs around which disrupt flow. By making the validation reactive like that, the user has instant feedback, rather than "do -> submit -> error -> repeat" which is a cycle that causes frustrations. Imagine you had a separate check for a single digit, or a check to see if there'a  capital in the password, and a check that you're using at least 1 special symbol... the user would trigger these warnings one at a time; they'd end up with about 5 errors (1 for the length, 1 for digit, 1 for capital, 1 for special characters, and then 1 for the repeat password because they forgot).

Looking at the code, it seems mostly fine for your purposes; the only thing I'd do is move `8` to a separate constant `MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH`.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to simply use what HTML has built-in:

```
<input type="password" required minlength="8">
```

will make that input mandatory and enforce a minimum of eight characters. (You can also use these attributes with `type="text"`.) It's no less secure than doing the validation in JavaScript, as you should still validate it server-side anyway. However, it isn't possible to check using HTML attributes that the two password fields are the same.

The `:optional` and `:required` CSS pseudo-classes can be used for styling the input based on the `required` attribute, but you can also use the more general `:valid` and `:invalid` pseudo-classes, which will also respond to things like `minlength`. You can check these pseudo-classes in JavaScript using [`Element#matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/matches), but you might have to also check for [non-standard naming](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/matches#Browser_compatibility) as `${prefix}MatchesSelector`.

**The only problem with this approach is the browser compatibility:** `minlength` is not supported except by Chrome and Opera, but you can [replace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10294291/6303733) it with the `pattern` attribute which has wider support, along with the `required` attribute. Except for Safari and IE <10.

More information about `<input>` is available at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) and [WebPlatform Docs](https://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/html/elements/input).

Answer (score 1):

In your example here, if I don't put in a name, use a password of < 8 characters, and my two passwords don't match, I will only get alerted to one issue; fix it, get another error, etc. If there are more fields it can get even more bothersome.  This can be fixed either as @Pimgd mentioned, as the person enters the information, or if you prefer to do it all at once at the end, you can set a general `error` variable that you alert after all the checks

```
var error = ""
var name = document.forms["registrationForm"]["username"].value;
if (name == null || name == "") {
        error += "Name must be filled out \n"
    }
var password = document.forms["registrationForm"]["password"].value;
var repeatPassword = document.forms["registrationForm"]["passwordAgain"].value;
if (password.length < 8) {
    error += "Password should contain 8 symbols or more \n"
    }
if (password != repeatPassword) {
    error += "Filled out passwords should match \n"
    }
if (error != "") {
    alert ("Please correct the following errors \n" + error)
    return false
    }
```